# How to check if an id comes into data on a particular date that it stays until an exit date

Tags: r, performance, data-cleaning

I have a data set that looks something like below. Basically, I am interested in checking if a particular id is present at the beginning of the year(in this case jan,1,2003) that it is present everyday until the end of the year( dec 31 2003) then starting the checking process over again with the start of next year as people might change from year to year but should not change within a year. If on certain day, an id is not present I would like to know which day and which id.

I first started with a for loop and checked every two days but this is super inefficient since my data set spans roughly 50 years and will grow later on with new data.

```
dates <- rep(seq(as.Date("2003/01/01"), as.Date("2004/12/31"), "days"),each = 3)
id <- rep(1:3,times = length(unique(dates))) 
df <- data.frame( dates = dates,id = id)
```

Edit:The above chunk has all the dates in it but if I delete for example id = 1 on the second day, the code should tell me it is missing so the count shouldn't be the same. I added the piece to delete the id = 1 on the second day below.

```
df <- df[-4,]
```

The code below will make the same data set but delete id = 1 for jan 2, 2003 and jan 3, 2003. I am trying to get something that returns the id that is missing and the date.

```
dates <- rep(seq(as.Date("2003/01/01"), as.Date("2004/12/31"), "days"),each = 3)
id <- rep(1:3,times = length(unique(dates))) 
df <- data.frame( dates = dates,id = id)
df <- df[-4,]
df <- df[-6,]
```

Comment: what do you get when do you this :  `df[2197,] == df[4,]` ? when I do that both columns return true, meaning the id and date are the same. is this the way you want your data ?

Comment: That was not suppose to happen! I found the mistake and edited the code!

Comment: OK great, can you also share the data where you would have missing data ? If that question needs to be answered.

Comment: I edited the question to remove two days. Thank you

Comment: I updated my answer below to answer your second question. There are other ways to do this but this is the first one that came to mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code chunk will count number of times a person appears in each year. if the answer is 365 or 366 in leap years a person was there everyday of the year.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dates <- rep(seq(as.Date("2003/01/01"), as.Date("2004/12/31"), "days"),each = 3)
id <- rep(1:3,times = length(unique(dates))) 
df <- data.frame( dates = dates,id = id)

    dfx <- df %>% 
          mutate(yrs = lubridate::year(dates)) %>% 
          group_by(id, dates) %>% 
          filter(row_number()==1) %>% 
          group_by(id, yrs) %>% 
          tally



#remove values
dfa <- df[c(-4,-6),]
```

The in oder to find the date of missing value add an indicator column to the data set. then fill in the missing dates by id. After this the val column will have missing values. Filter the data to get the dates where it went missing.

```
dfx <- dfa %>% 
        mutate(val = 1) %>% 
       complete(nesting(id),
                dates = seq(min(dates),max(dates),by = "day")) %>% 
        filter(is.na(val))
```

Comment: This looks close but it doesn't seem to be counting the number of the times the id appears and instead maybe counting the number of days. I deleted the 4th row which contains id = 1 and it still returned the same count.

Comment: yea it is counting days by id, in your question it wanted to know if a person was present on every day which the above code will do. I just read further and will see if I can answer the second part.

Comment: Yes but when I delete id = 1 for two days in 2003 , it still returns that it was there 365 days so I think it is just counting the number of days in 2003. I'm not to familiar with the dplyr package so I'm not to sure where the breakdown is happening.

Comment: Yes, the one I provided has everything in it. Then to test the code on whether it would pick up on an id being missing I deleted the 4 row and ran the code again. I edited the question to add this portion to make testing clear. Sorry.

Comment: Your  code works perfectly now for counting the dates by id. Thanks for the catch. If delete a row, the count changes now.

Comment: Thanks! Works as desired