# Insert rows with zeros in data frames with nested groups

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data, zero

I have a data set with nested groups and with some rows missing:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Gr1 = rep(c("x", "y"), each = 10),
                 Gr2 = rep(c("x1", "x2", "y1", "y2"), each = 5),
                 ID = paste0(rep(c("x", "y"), each = 10), letters[1:5]),
                 var1 = round(rnorm(20), 2),
                 var2 = round(rnorm(20), 2))

rmv.rows <- sample(1:20, 5)
df <- df[-rmv.rows, ]

   Gr1 Gr2 ID  var1  var2
1    x  x1 xa -0.56 -1.07
3    x  x1 xc  1.56 -1.03
4    x  x1 xd  0.07 -0.73
6    x  x2 xa  1.72 -1.69
7    x  x2 xb  0.46  0.84
9    x  x2 xd -0.69 -1.14
10   x  x2 xe -0.45  1.25
11   y  y1 ya  1.22  0.43
12   y  y1 yb  0.36 -0.30
15   y  y1 ye -0.56  0.82
16   y  y2 ya  1.79  0.69
17   y  y2 yb  0.50  0.55
18   y  y2 yc -1.97 -0.06
19   y  y2 yd  0.70 -0.31
20   y  y2 ye -0.47 -0.38
```

I would like to fill missing rows (i.e. combinations of `Gr1`, `Gr2` and `ID`) by zeros.

I tried approaches as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53729693/insert-rows-with-zeros-in-data-frames-in-r), however it returns all possible combinations of `Gr1`, `Gr2` and `ID` and not those present in data. In other words, I would like to insert only existing combinations of `Gr1`, `Gr2` and `ID`. The desired output should be:

```
   Gr1 Gr2 ID  var1  var2
1    x  x1 xa -0.56 -1.07
2    x  x1 xb  0.00  0.00
3    x  x1 xc  1.56 -1.03
4    x  x1 xd  0.07 -0.73
5    x  x1 xe  0.00  0.00
6    x  x2 xa  1.72 -1.69
7    x  x2 xb  0.46  0.84
8    x  x2 xc  0.00  0.00
9    x  x2 xd -0.69 -1.14
10   x  x2 xe -0.45  1.25
11   y  y1 ya  1.22  0.43
12   y  y1 yb  0.36 -0.30
13   y  y1 yc  0.00  0.00
14   y  y1 yd  0.00  0.00
15   y  y1 ye -0.56  0.82
16   y  y2 ya  1.79  0.69
17   y  y2 yb  0.50  0.55
18   y  y2 yc -1.97 -0.06
19   y  y2 yd  0.70 -0.31
20   y  y2 ye -0.47 -0.38
```

Comment: Do you need `complete`  `df %>% group_by(Gr1, Gr2) %>% complete(ID, fill = list(var1 = 0, var2 = 0))`

Comment: Unfortunately, this will also create combinations e.g. `x`, `x2` and `ya` which is not desirable.

Comment: you can use ifelse(round(rnorm (20),2) == 0.00, rnorm(1),round(rnorm (20),2))

Comment: @akrun did you mean: `df %>% group_by(Gr1) %>% complete(Gr2, ID, fill = list(var1 = 0, var2 = 0))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an option that uses `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
all_comb <- df[, CJ(Gr2, ID, unique = TRUE), by = Gr1]
df_out <- df[all_comb, on = .(Gr1, Gr2, ID)]
df_out[is.na(df_out)] <- 0
df_out

#     Gr1 Gr2 ID  var1  var2
#  1:   x  x1 xa -0.56 -1.07
#  2:   x  x1 xb -0.23 -0.22
#  3:   x  x1 xc  1.56 -1.03
#  4:   x  x1 xd  0.07 -0.73
#  5:   x  x1 xe  0.13 -0.63
#  6:   x  x2 xa  0.00  0.00
#  7:   x  x2 xb  0.00  0.00
#  8:   x  x2 xc  0.00  0.00
#  9:   x  x2 xd -0.69 -1.14
# 10:   x  x2 xe -0.45  1.25
# 11:   y  y1 ya  0.00  0.00
# 12:   y  y1 yb  0.36 -0.30
# 13:   y  y1 yc  0.40  0.90
# 14:   y  y1 yd  0.11  0.88
# 15:   y  y1 ye  0.00  0.00
# 16:   y  y2 ya  1.79  0.69
# 17:   y  y2 yb  0.50  0.55
# 18:   y  y2 yc -1.97 -0.06
# 19:   y  y2 yd  0.70 -0.31
# 20:   y  y2 ye -0.47 -0.38
```

#### PS.

For users that have *not yet* updated to R 3.6 here is the data produced by OP code in the current version of R:

```
df <- structure(list(Gr1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("x", "y"), class = "factor"), 
    Gr2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("x1", "x2", "y1", "y2"), class = "factor"), 
    ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("xa", "xb", "xc", "xd", 
    "xe", "ya", "yb", "yc", "yd", "ye"), class = "factor"), var1 = c(-0.56, 
    -0.23, 1.56, 0.07, 0.13, -0.69, -0.45, 0.36, 0.4, 0.11, 1.79, 
    0.5, -1.97, 0.7, -0.47), var2 = c(-1.07, -0.22, -1.03, -0.73, 
    -0.63, -1.14, 1.25, -0.3, 0.9, 0.88, 0.69, 0.55, -0.06, -0.31, 
    -0.38)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @avid_useR I think the issue is that the printout shown by OP of `df` is not correct.

Comment: @avid_useR shouldn't be done the other way around, that is: the code for the reproducible data is what we should go by?

Comment: @avid_useR wierd, I don't (using R 3.6), could it be that you are using an older version?

Comment: Of course I did. Just checked and sample() --- it did effectively get updated in 3.6: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2019/000641.html

Comment: @avid_useR  ARE you sure you are not using an old version of R?

Comment: I am, but so is OP. Since you have a newer/different version of R installed, you should provide the data you're using if you can't reproduce what OP has provided.

Comment: @avid_useR I don't know what the issue is. I am using the current version (R version 3.6.0, released on 2019-04-26.) and you are using an old version.

Comment: The issue being readers would likely get confused that your output doesn't match the input and there is no way to get your output if they have an older version. It's good now that you've provided reproducible data.

Answer (score 2):

We can do it with `complete` and `nesting` from `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Gr1) %>%
  complete(nesting(ID), nesting(Gr2), fill = list(var1 = 0, var2 = 0)) %>%
  arrange(Gr1, Gr2, ID) %>%
  select(Gr1, Gr2, ID, everything())
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 20 x 5
# Groups:   Gr1 [2]
   Gr1   Gr2   ID     var1  var2
   <fct> <fct> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 x     x1    xa    -0.56 -1.07
 2 x     x1    xb     0     0   
 3 x     x1    xc     1.56 -1.03
 4 x     x1    xd     0.07 -0.73
 5 x     x1    xe     0     0   
 6 x     x2    xa     1.72 -1.69
 7 x     x2    xb     0.46  0.84
 8 x     x2    xc     0     0   
 9 x     x2    xd    -0.69 -1.14
10 x     x2    xe    -0.45  1.25
11 y     y1    ya     1.22  0.43
12 y     y1    yb     0.36 -0.3 
13 y     y1    yc     0     0   
14 y     y1    yd     0     0   
15 y     y1    ye    -0.56  0.82
16 y     y2    ya     1.79  0.69
17 y     y2    yb     0.5   0.55
18 y     y2    yc    -1.97 -0.06
19 y     y2    yd     0.7  -0.31
20 y     y2    ye    -0.47 -0.38
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `expand` and `left_join`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(Gr1) %>%
  expand(nesting(ID), nesting(Gr2)) %>% 
  left_join(df) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(var1:var2), replace_na, 0)  %>% 
  arrange(Gr1, Gr2, ID) %>% 
  select(names(df))
# A tibble: 20 x 5
# Groups:   Gr1 [2]
#   Gr1   Gr2   ID     var1  var2
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 x     x1    xa    -0.56 -1.07
# 2 x     x1    xb     0     0   
# 3 x     x1    xc     1.56 -1.03
# 4 x     x1    xd     0.07 -0.73
# 5 x     x1    xe     0     0   
# 6 x     x2    xa     1.72 -1.69
# 7 x     x2    xb     0.46  0.84
# 8 x     x2    xc     0     0   
# 9 x     x2    xd    -0.69 -1.14
#10 x     x2    xe    -0.45  1.25
#11 y     y1    ya     1.22  0.43
#12 y     y1    yb     0.36 -0.3 
#13 y     y1    yc     0     0   
#14 y     y1    yd     0     0   
#15 y     y1    ye    -0.56  0.82
#16 y     y2    ya     1.79  0.69
#17 y     y2    yb     0.5   0.55
#18 y     y2    yc    -1.97 -0.06
#19 y     y2    yd     0.7  -0.31
#20 y     y2    ye    -0.47 -0.38
```